# How to write scheme cond so it returns the value of a nested cond

Tags: scheme, racket

I have a function that basically goes

```
(cond
    (
    (cond)
    (cond)
    )
)
```

At the moment scheme seems like a foreign language to me. My question is simple. How do I get the first cond to return true only if the nested have also returned true. From what I've gathered the nested (cond)(cond) is being treated as the test for the first right? All I keep getting is #void for a return.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
(cond ((cond ((= 1 2) #f)
             ((= 2 3) #f)
             (else #f))
       #t)
      ((cond ((= 3 4) #f)
             ((= 4 5) #f)
             (else #t)) ; this is the only #t condition
       #t))             ; hence this #t value is returned
```

In the above example, only the last `else` in the second inner `cond` returns true, which in turns returns true in the condition of the outermost `cond`.

But really, why would you want to do such a thing? if you have multiple conditions, just use different branches of a single `cond`. Maybe you're misunderstanding how it's supposed to be used? think of it as a series of `if-else if-else if-else` statements in other programming languages.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to do that. Imagine this example:

```scm
(cond ((cond ((< x 10) #t)
             ((> x 20) #t)
             (else #f))
       #t)
      ((cond ((< y 10) #t)
             ((> y 20) #t)
             (else #f))
       #t))
```

This can easily be flattended down to one `cond`:

```scm
(cond ((< x 10) #t)
      ((> x 20) #t)
      ((< y 10) #t)
      ((> y 20) #t)
      (else #f))
```

You could use `or` to take the first true value. This works for all true values, not just `#t` (Everything not `#f` is considered true)

```scm
(or (cond ((< x 10) 'small-x)
          ((> x 20) 'big-x)
          (else #f))
    (cond ((< y 10) 'small-y)
          ((> y 20) 'big-y)
          (else #f)))
```

Even if you can use `cond` for every conditional its probably wise to only use it where there are either side effects involved or there are more than one predicate (like elseif in Algol languages) and use `if` as the conditional for one predicate. Eg. you can write one of the sub-`cond`s above to this:

```scm
(cond ((>= 20 x 10) #f)
      (else #t))
```

Now I would automatically have changed from `cond` to `if` since it's no longer nessecary for a `cond`:

```scm
(if (>= 20 x 10)
    #f
    #t)
```

Perhaps a bad example since the whole `if` can be written `(not (>= 20 x 10))`.